# TypeScript doesn't catch undefined variable?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand TypeScript better. I've found that if I write a bug like so:

```
function doStuff() {
    if (physician.email == "george@gmail.com")
    {
         var physician = {email: "bob@gmail.com", name: "Dr. Bob"};
         /* .... */
    } }
```

TypeScript will NOT catch the problem that the physician object is defined AFTER we attempted to use one of its properties. This results in a run-time error of:

> Type error: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined.

Why doesn't the TypeScript transpiler catch stuff like this? Using TypeScript 2.0 I believe.

Comment: Side note: this is one reason to avoid using `var`.  It's a lot harder to accidentally cause bugs like this if you can't use the variable before declaring it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript, declarations (though not initializations) of `var` variables are implicitly moved to the beginning of the containing function, and `var` variables are implicitly initialized to `undefined` until the user-written initializer is reached.  By default, TypeScript takes the position that reading the implicit `undefined` value is legitimate.  One way you can make it an error is to enable the `strictNullChecks` compiler option (or the umbrella `strict` option) and give the variable a type that does not include `undefined` (which happens automatically by inference in your example).  Here's [the documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#assigned-before-use-checking) for that feature.  tslint also has a [`no-use-before-declare` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-use-before-declare/) that should detect the problem.

In contrast to `var` variables, using a `let` or `const` variable before its declaration is always a compile error in TypeScript.  This is one of the reasons that `let` (or `const`) is highly recommended over `var`.  Use of a `let` variable after it is declared (and implicitly initialized to `undefined`) but before it is initialized by user code follows the same rules as `var`.